# XmlSerializer is throwing InvalidOperationException when using the generic type constraint where

Tags: c#, .net, generics, xmlserializer

When I try to run the following code (two separated assemblies)

#### ClassLibrary.cs

```
public interface ITest
{
}
```

#### Program.cs

```
using System;

public class TestClass
{
    public void Test<T>(T x) where T : ITest { }
}

static class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)         
    {
        new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(TestClass));
    }
}
```

Compiled in Windows 7 64-Bit using the following commands:

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc /target:library ClassLibrary.cs
>
> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc /reference:ClassLibrary.dll Program.cs

I'm getting the this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class
>   (result=1). error CS0012: The type
>   ITest is defined in an assembly that
>   is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly ClassLibrary,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null hinzu.
>
> at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly
>   parent, String ns,
>   XmlSerializerCompilerParameters
>   xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
>   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[]
>   xmlMappings, Type[] types, String
>   defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence,
>   XmlSerializerCompilerParameters
>   parameters, Assembly assembly,
>   Hashtable assemblies)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[]
>   xmlMappings, Type[] types, String
>   defaultNamespace, String location,
>   Evidence evidence)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping
>   xmlMapping, Type type, String
>   defaultNamespace)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type
>   type, String defaultNamespace)    at
>   Program.Main(String[] args)

Removing the *where T : ITest* from *TestClass* or not using generics at all (e.g. using *public void Test(ITest x)*) will prevent the exception from being thrown but I need this construct in my real application.

Do anybody understand why the XmlSerializer is unable to handle the where constraint?

Comment: random guess: is an old version of ClassLibrary in your GAC?

Comment: @Jimmy: no - because the problem looked very strange to me I did setup a complete new set of files and just use csc.exe to compile. Changing the name of ClassLibrary.cs does not help in any way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are [out of luck](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/203076/xmlserializer-does-not-work-on-type-with-constrained-generic-method). Here's the response from Microsoft about this issue:

> Thank you for submitting this issue.
>   Unfortunately, we have decided that it
>   will not be addressed because the risk
>   of the fix outweighs its benefit. By
>   the time the next opportunity to make
>   this change comes about, the hope is
>   that the new serialization
>   technologies in a future version of
>   the Windows Communication Foundation
>   will address your scenario. If this
>   issue is causing significant negative
>   business impact, please contact
>   Microsoft Product Support Services. I
>   regret that we could not provide a
>   better resolution. Rest assured that
>   we seriously considered this issue - a
>   Won't Fix decision is never easy to
>   make.

This basically says the you should use [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) instead of [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) or change your object structure.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you may be VERY close, and not even know it.

Try to define an empty helper class inside your ClassLibrary assembly and put `[Serializable, XmlInclude(SerializationReferenceHelper)]` just above `public class TestClass`.

The issue is that the Xml parser doesn't know about the second class because it is in a different assembly and is only referenced by the where constraint in your code. Yes, Microsoft could write a little ditty to look in all of the known assemblies... not sure why they don't. But for now this might work.

#### ClassLibrary

```
public class SerializationReferenceHelper { }
public interface ITest { }
```

#### Program

```
[Serializable, XmlInclude(typeof(SerializationReferenceHelper))]
public class TestClass
{
    public void Test<T>(T x) where T : ITest { }
}

static class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)         
    {
        new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(TestClass));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

> The type ITest is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. **You
>   must add a reference to assembly
>   ClassLibrary**

Have you done this?

Comment: take a look at the command I do execute - the argument /reference:ClassLibrary.dll is doing exactly that.